# Return in the method overloading

Tags: java, methods, return, overloading

I'm new to Java and I'm learning it myself. I met a trouble when I try the method overloading. This is the code

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        calculateScore();
        calculateScore(500);
        calculateScore("Duy", 600);
        calcFeetAndInchesToCentimetres(100, 3.5);
        calcFeetAndInchesToCentimetres(100*12 + 3.5);
    }

 public static double calcFeetAndInchesToCentimetres(double feet, double inches) {
        if (feet >= 0 && inches >= 0 && inches <= 12) {
            double footToInches = feet * 12;
            double centimetres = (inches + footToInches) * 2.54;
            System.out.println("The value in centimetres is " + centimetres + " cm.");
            return centimetres;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public static double calcFeetAndInchesToCentimetres(double inches) {
        if (inches >= 0){
            double inchesToFeet = inches / 12;
            double inchesRemain = inches - (inchesToFeet * 12);
            calcFeetAndInchesToCentimetres(inchesToFeet, inchesRemain);
            return 0;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
```

My problem is when I take the `return 0` from the second method, the debugger says "missing return statement". Then I tried to put `return calcFeetAndInchesToCentimetres(inches);`, it works but the program runs for about many thousands times.

Then I put `return 0` and everything is OK. But I don't understand why I can't put the `return calcFeetAndInchesToCentimetres(inches);` and why do I need a return statement when the method above (with 2 parameters) had it alredy. And if I want to have the value of centimetres converted when I execute the second method (with "inches" parameter only) what do I have to do?

One other thing I've realized that in this blockcode

```
double inchesToFeet = inches / 12;
        double inchesRemain = inches - (inchesToFeet * 12);
        calcFeetAndInchesToCentimetres(inchesToFeet, inchesRemain);
```

the inchesRemain will be 0? But the method works very well. When I change `inchesToFeet = inches % 12`, it just not shows anything. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should just be:

```
public static double calcFeetAndInchesToCentimetres(double inches) {
    if (inches >= 0){
        double inchesToFeet = inches / 12;
        double inchesRemain = inches - (inchesToFeet * 12);
        return calcFeetAndInchesToCentimetres(inchesToFeet, inchesRemain);
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

You said you've tried `return calcFeetAndInchesToCentimetres(inches);` but that's just calling your method recursively and it recurses forever as there is no stopping condition.

Comment: The return is to put the value in the method right? I mean if I don't put return what will happens then? Because I only put return when I need to use the variable declared inside the method after called it

Comment: Wow, that's a pretty big misconception of what return is. Let aside `void` methods, `return` is the most important thing in a method, and it's certainly not for accessing variables inside the method. The very purpose of a function is to take a list (possibly empty) of parameters and to return a value depending on them. Without a return statement, you can only write `void` methods, which **do** stuff rather than **computing** stuff. You should really read about functions/methods because you cannot afford any misunderstanding on these notions

Comment: Can you explain it more in detail please? And can you suggest me a book for the java programming? I'm Vietnamese and all the web I searched just says that the 'return' is used when we need the method to keep the information and return it. And I don't understand why 'return' will call the method again (in my code)?

Comment: `return` doesn't call your method again, you are calling your method when you write `calcFeetAndInchesToCentimetres(inches)`. Have you done maths ? If you did, then you kno what a function is. It's not different in programming, a function takes parameters and returns a value. That's the only meaning of `return`

Comment: Thanks. I got it. And the last thing I wanna ask is the edited part in my question. Have you seen that? I think it's an error @@

Comment: In the overloaded method, I've tried to convert inches to feet by 'inchesToFeet=inches/12' then calculate the inchesRemains= inches - inchesToFeet*12. I think the result of inchesRemains is 0? And when I replace it by 'inchesToFeet=inches%12' the code doesn't show anything to the screen when I run it. Sorry for my English:(.

Comment: Are you just trying any combination of operators ? `%` is totally different from `*`. You know, it'd be easier if you shown actual code rather than trying to explain what modification you're trying on the code of the question. That might be worth asking another, separate question

Answer (score 3):

With method overloading, you have two different methods.

1. `calcFeetAndInchesToCentimetres` that takes a single argument
2. `calcFeetAndInchesToCentimetres` that takes two arguments

Now when you call `calcFeetAndInchesToCentimetres(inches);` you are calling the one that takes a single argument. If you call that from inside itself, it will continue calling itself infinite times. This is the error you are seeing.

If you replace that with `return calcFeetAndInchesToCentimetres(inchesToFeet, inchesRemain);` that will call the other method - the one that takes two arguments. That's what you actually want to do.

Fixed version:

```
public static double calcFeetAndInchesToCentimetres(double inches) {
    if (inches >= 0){
        double inchesToFeet = inches / 12;
        double inchesRemain = inches - (inchesToFeet * 12);
        return calcFeetAndInchesToCentimetres(inchesToFeet, inchesRemain);
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    calculateScore();
    calculateScore(500);
    calculateScore("Duy", 600);
    calcFeetAndInchesToCentimetres(100, 3.5);
    calcFeetAndInchesToCentimetres(100*12 + 3.5);
}

public static double calcFeetAndInchesToCentimetres(double feet, double inches) {
    if (feet >= 0 && inches >= 0 && inches <= 12) {
        double footToInches = feet * 12;
        double centimetres = (inches + footToInches) * 2.54;
        System.out.println("The value in centimetres is " + centimetres + " cm.");
        return centimetres;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
public static double calcFeetAndInchesToCentimetres(double inches) {
    if (inches >= 0){
        double inchesToFeet = inches / 12;
        double inchesRemain = inches - (inchesToFeet * 12);
        calcFeetAndInchesToCentimetres(inchesToFeet, inchesRemain);
        return 0; //Here
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
```

If you remove return 0 it is showing missing return statement because you are in a if-else loop.
Lets say your input inches is less than 0 then it will go the else part and return the -1.. but if the inches inputed are more than 0 then it will go to the if condition and when it will reach the end of the if statement then there would be nothing to return so for a if-else condition both if and else should return something.

Other way to go around this is make a local variable out of if-else condition and return if after the else part is done.. In this way weather it goes in if or else part of the code both times there would be some value for that local variable to be returned..

Now for second part of your question:
your code will look like

```
line 1   public static double calcFeetAndInchesToCentimetres(double inches) {
```

line 2   `if (inches >= 0){`
 line 3       `double inchesToFeet = inches / 12;`
 line 4       `double inchesRemain = inches - (inchesToFeet * 12);`
line 5       `calcFeetAndInchesToCentimetres(inchesToFeet, inchesRemain);`
 line 6       `return calcFeetAndInchesToCentimetres(inches);`
    `} else {`
        `return -1;`
    `}`

So in this case you are calling the same method itself again and again..
You start from line 1 go till line 6 then you call the same method and the execution starts again and line 1 will be executed till line 6 and again line 1 over and over again until all memory is lost and a stackoverflow occours..

Best practiced code can look like this:

```
public static double calcFeetAndInchesToCentimetres(double feet, double inches) {
    double centimetres = 0.0;
    if (feet >= 0 && inches >= 0 && inches <= 12) {
        double footToInches = feet * 12;
        centimetres = (inches + footToInches) * 2.54;
        System.out.println("The value in centimetres is " + centimetres + " cm.");
    } else {
        centimetres = -1;
    }
    return centimetres;
}


public static double calcFeetAndInchesToCentimetres(double inches) {
    double centimeters = 0;
    if (inches >= 0) {
        double inchesToFeet = inches / 12;
        double inchesRemain = inches - (inchesToFeet * 12);
        centimeters = calcFeetAndInchesToCentimetres(inchesToFeet, inchesRemain);

    } else {
        centimeters = -1;
    }
    return centimeters; //Here
}
```

Comment: I don't believe a single return statement is a better practice than multiple return statements. Actually, I have a strong preference to the former in most cases. Effectively final variables make code clearer than variables assigned multiple times.

Comment: This means I'm not forced to put a return in each if and else blockcode?

Comment: @Dici That depends on individual coding practices.. I strongly follow one return statement.. there are many conditions where the code is long and whenever we have multiple return statements there are times when we forget that and when we execute we think where we went wrong.. Why it is not returning the required output.

Comment: @DuyNghĩaTrần No you are not forced to put return in each block.. just make sure you are returning something just before the closing braces of the method itself.

Comment: I would argue a method should not be long in the first place :p

Comment: @DIci Yes true.. But not everyone follow this kind of practice.. I have seen people coding every god damn thing In one method.. I hate those people..

Comment: I have seen some too :D